# Use html <a> tag with same z-index?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have slider and when i mouseover on slider play button is displaying, but slider images are inside a tag and when play button is not hidden i can't click on images inside a tag. i tried set same z-index for both (slider images and play button) but still not working

i need to click on play button when it shown and go to link placed bottom of this play button
if it is possible please help, and sorry for my bad english.

Main question: how can i click on play button with and redirect to link placed inside a tag?

Here is image how slider looks like [onmouseover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52AXe.jpg) and image when mouse is [out of slider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOgbm.jpg)

here is my **html** code:

```html
<style type="text/css">
    #slider-play-button-container{
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 2;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        text-align: center;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    #slider-play-button{
        position: relative;
        top: 25vh;
        width: 2vw;
        opacity: 0;
    }
    .slide-img{
        width: 100%;
        height: 55vh;
        object-fit: cover;
        border-radius: .7vw;
        overflow:hidden;
    }
</style>

<main class=content>
  <span id="slider-play-button-container"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/md7vyI8.png" id="slider-play-button"></span>
  <div id="slider">
    <a href="Link to go after play button click" target="_Blank">
      <h3 class="slider-movie-name">ჯონ ვიკი: III თავი - პარაბელუმი</h3>
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/OP3AITl.jpg" class="slide-img">
    </a>
    <a href="Another link to go after play button click" target="_Blank">
      <h3 class="slider-movie-name">შურისმაძიებლები: დასასრული</h3>
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/3vDzVHa.jpg" class="slide-img">
    </a>
  </div>
</main>

<script>

    function bid(n){return document.getElementById(n)}
    function qs(n){return document.querySelector(n)}
    function qsa(n){return document.querySelectorAll(n)}

    let slider = bid('slider');

    let arrowTop = bid('slide_arrow_top');
    let arrowBottom = bid('slide_arrow_bottom');

    let sliderImage = qsa('.slide-img');
    let sliderPlayButtonContainer = bid('slider-play-button-container');
    let sliderPlayButton = bid('slider-play-button');

    let count = 0;
    let imageOffset = 0;
    
    let imgOffset = 0;
    var slideInterval;
    let sliderImageOffset;
    
    
    /* autoscroll */
    
    window.addEventListener('load',winLoadForSlide);
    function winLoadForSlide(){
    
        /* slider */
        slider.addEventListener('wheel',slideMouseScroll);
        arrowBottom.addEventListener('click',scrollBottom);
        arrowTop.addEventListener('click',scrollTop);
    
        function bottomSlide(){
            if (count < 4) {
                count++;
            }
            imageOffset = sliderImage[count].offsetTop;
            slider.scrollTo(0,imageOffset);
        }
    
        function topSlide(){
            if (count > 0) {
                count--;
            }
            imageOffset = sliderImage[count].offsetTop;
            slider.scrollTo(0,imageOffset-5);
        }
    
        function slideMouseScroll(){
            if (event.deltaY < 0){
                topSlide();
            }else if (event.deltaY > 0){
                bottomSlide();
            }
        }
    
        function scrollBottom(){
            bottomSlide();
        }
    
        function scrollTop(){
            topSlide();
        }
    
        slideInterval = setInterval(repeatScroll,100 * 20);
    
        function showSliderPlayButton(){
            sliderPlayButton.style.transform = "scale(5)";
            sliderPlayButton.style.opacity = "1";
            sliderPlayButton.style.transition = "250ms";
        }
        function hideSliderPlayButton(){
            sliderPlayButton.style.transform = "scale(1)";
            sliderPlayButton.style.opacity = "0";
            sliderPlayButton.style.transition = "250ms";
        }
    
        [slider,arrowBottom,arrowTop,sliderPlayButtonContainer,sliderPlayButton].forEach(slideElements => {
            slideElements.addEventListener('mouseover',()=>{
                clearInterval(slideInterval);
            });
            slideElements.ondragstart = function(){ return false; }
        });
    
        [slider,sliderPlayButtonContainer,sliderPlayButton].forEach(slideElementsWithoutButtons => {
            slideElementsWithoutButtons.addEventListener('mouseover',()=>{
                showSliderPlayButton();
            });
        });
    
        slider.addEventListener('mouseleave',()=>{
            slideInterval = setInterval(repeatScroll,100 * 20);
            hideSliderPlayButton();
        });
    
        function repeatScroll(){
    
                    if( (slider.scrollHeight - slider.scrollTop - slider.clientHeight) !== 4 ){
                        if (imgOffset < 4) {
                            imgOffset++;
                        }
                        sliderImageOffset = sliderImage[imgOffset].offsetTop;
                        slider.scrollTo(0,sliderImageOffset);
    
                    }else{
                        imgOffset = 0;
                        slider.scrollTo(0,0);
                    }
        }
    
        /* END slider */
    }
    
    /* END autoscroll */

</script>
```

Comment: You sample code is missing the relevant CSS.

Comment: please read main question and see provided image to help me

Comment: Please provide a [mre] to help us help you.

Comment: Try using `position: absolute;` on the tag you're applying `z-index` to.

Comment: @Nanoo not working

Comment: @Gurami Could you post a complete code snippet which clearly showcases the problem - e.g. including the mouseover bits.

Comment: `opacity: 0;` ?

Comment: @Greedo onmouseover opacity is 1 using javascript. i have different problem.

Comment: @obscure here is code html and css. i need to go on link after play button click. image click is working fine but i need to do same on playbutton click

Comment: @Gurami yeah but we need to see your actual JavaScript code that takes care of the mouseover effect so we can assist you. Without it's just a shot in the dark.

Comment: Yes, we need the JS too

Comment: Okay i edited my question with javascript. Could you help me now please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

parentElement property helped a lot to solve my problem

```
playButtonATagHref = sliderImage[imgOffset].parentElement.href;

sliderPlayButton.addEventListener('click',()=>{
    window.location.href = playButtonATagHref;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to get around this problem.

One would involve getting rid of the anchor tags altogether, grouping each image inside a single  container and assigning a click event listener to each one to ultimately open the link. If you then add another click listener to the arrow button which executes `event.preventDefault();` the click event will be passed through to the object below - the `<div>` including your image.

If you want to keep the anchor tags, things are a little tricky. Luckily there are some helpful JavaScript functions, foremost `document.elementsFromPoint(x,y)`.

If you feed the current mouse coordinates to this function - e.g. by clicking on the arrow button - it will return an array of objects below this point.
This array contains the anchor element in the background, so it's just a matter of picking it out of the array, get the link assigned to it and open it using the `window.open()` command.

Here's an example:

```js
function bid(n) {
  return document.getElementById(n)
}
let sliderPlayButtonContainer = bid('slider-play-button-container');
let sliderPlayButton = bid('slider-play-button');

sliderPlayButtonContainer.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  var list = document.elementsFromPoint(event.clientX, event.clientY)
  var anchorElement = list.find(element => element instanceof HTMLImageElement && element.className == 'slide-img').parentElement;
  window.open(anchorElement.href, anchorElement.target);
});


function showSliderPlayButton() {
  sliderPlayButton.style.transform = "scale(5)";
  sliderPlayButton.style.opacity = "1";
  sliderPlayButton.style.transition = "250ms";
}


sliderPlayButtonContainer.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
  showSliderPlayButton();
});
```

```css
#slider-play-button-container {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#slider-play-button {
  position: relative;
  top: 25vh;
  width: 2vw;
  opacity: 1;
}

.slide-img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 55vh;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: .7vw;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<span id="slider-play-button-container"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/md7vyI8.png" id="slider-play-button"></span>
<div id="slider">
  <a href="https://www.startpage.com" target="_blank">
    <h3 class="slider-movie-name">ჯონ ვიკი: III თავი - პარაბელუმი</h3>
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/OP3AITl.jpg" class="slide-img">
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time i saw your answer jus a minute ago and before i found simple solution

Comment: Glad you got it sorted yourself!